# Processing - defining a camera

Tags: java, 3d, camera, processing

I am currently beginning to learn Processing within a class.
I am trying to define a camera however I am unsure about the example given. 
I understand the camera parameters and what they mean:

`camera(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ)`

However, this is what we have been given and I would just like someone to clear it up.

Observe what happens with the camera if you provide mouse coordinates:

```
camera(mouseX, mouseY, camera_z, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

Now I understand the mouseX mouseY. But the camera_z is what throws the errors. I am unsure what this is meant to do as it is not defined. I know it should be a variable and when I put it as say 1, it changes it. But was hoping someone could clear up what maybe is meant by this as It is confusing me.

Is it meant to mean something?

Should I just change the parameter to a number?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for whoever wrote the example, but my guess is that `camera_z` is just a placeholder. It's not a predefined variable like `mouseX`, `mouseY`, `width`, or `height`. That's why you're getting an error.

My guess is that the author intended you to define the variable yourself, but they didn't want to include that because the actual value isn't very relevant, and they wanted to encourage you to try out different values yourself.